# WinAPI WndProc silently fails when using maps

Tags: c++, windows, class, winapi, wndproc

First, let me say I'm new to using WinAPI, and I'm trying to learn the basics. That said, I'm trying to create a few objects to make my future work with WinAPI much easier. One of those is a Window Class...class. The other is, of course, a Window class.

I'm trying to make message processing into something simple, like myClassInst.addHandler(WM_PAINT, PaintFunction). For that, I figured I'd use a map that maps uints to function pointers. That seems fine.

But now, the messages aren't being processed. After some debugging, I found that whenever I try to use the map in any way inside my class's WndProc handler, it just silently fails. I get no compile errors, no runtime errors, no crashes; the function just immediately ends there until the next message comes in. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Maybe someone can help me?

Below is a snippet of my code, all in the private section of my WinClass class. The static dummyProc message-passer is the only way I found to allow a class-specific WndProc, so that's there. That's working, as the first part of my WndProc myHandler does, in fact, work, as evidenced by the debug message's output. It just stops the second I try and use the map, even just to get its size.

*Note: WindowFunction is a typedef to a pointer to a function taking an HWND parameter.

```
  std::map<unsigned int, WindowFunction> messageMap;

  static LRESULT CALLBACK dummyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    WinClass* context=(WinClass*)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
    return context->myHandler(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }

  LRESULT CALLBACK myHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::cout<<"Message: "<<msg<<std::endl; // This gets output
    std::cout<<"  Contains "<<messageMap.size()<<" items"<<std::endl; // This does not
    std::cout<<"  And me!"<<std::endl; // Nothing works below the map usage.

    for (std::map<unsigned int, WindowFunction>::iterator it=messageMap.begin(); it!=messageMap.end(); ++it) {
      std::cout<<"  Have: "<<it->first<<std::endl;
      if (msg==it->first) {
        (it->second)(hwnd);
        break;
      }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
```

**EDIT** So, after some further testing, I've discovered some more information. The context value is always 0, and while I don't understand how that would even allow the myHandler to get called, it is a problem. So I've changed my code to try and set the GWL_USERDATA from the WM_CREATE message...and what I've found is that my dummyProc is never getting the WM_CREATE message.

Below is the new dummyProc, complete with debugging output:

```
  static LRESULT CALLBACK dummyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::cout<<"Create would be "<<WM_CREATE<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The message was "<<msg<<std::endl;
    if (msg==WM_CREATE) {
      SetLastError(0);
      SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, lParam);
      std::cout<<"ERROR: "<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
    }
    long thelong=GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
    std::cout<<"Long: "<<thelong<<std::endl;
    WinClass* context=(WinClass*)thelong;
    std::cout<<"Context: "<<context<<std::endl;
    return context->myHandler(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
```

What it says is that WM_CREATE has a value of 1, but the messages come in starting from 36, then 129 and 130. What happened to my WM_CREATE message?

Here's the code that creates the window itself:

hand = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                                  myClass.myName,
                                  title,
                                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                  x, y, 
                                  w, h, 
                                  parent,
                                  NULL, 
                                  inst, 
                                  &myClass);

Most of those parameters are arguments passed to the Window class's constructor (where this code is). The myClass parameter is a WinClass instance. All WinClass instances set dummyProc as their WndProc handler. Testing shows that &myClass is indeed a valid non-NULL pointer when this is called.

So what's preventing the WM_CREATE message?

Comment: Have you checked that `context` has the right value?

Comment: I know it must, because as I said, the function does get called and the first part outputs just fine. Everything in myHandler works up until I try to use the map.

Comment: "The function gets called" proves no such thing.  This is "undefined behavior", it's allowed to work halfway.  In particular, the function can be found without a correct `this` pointer, because it isn't `virtual`.  And the top half of the function (the part that works) hasn't used the `this` pointer yet.

Comment: `WM_CREATE` gets sent, but it's nowhere near the first.  In my answer I mentioned `WM_NCCREATE`, which is usually quite early, although still not the first.  Try reading my whole answer, and also the Raymond Chen blog post I linked to.

Comment: What do you mean by "All WinClass instances set dummyProc as their WndProc handler. "  Aren't you setting the handler in `RegisterClass`?

Comment: So I've learned below >_< . But now that I've discovered the context is being set to NULL, I've done some more testing. As you can see from the edit above, I've update the dummyProc in a way that should handle this properly now...except it's never receiving the WM_CREATE message. Any idea why that might be, looking at the new code?

Comment: Well, you still crash on every message that comes before `WM_CREATE`...  Perhaps you want `if (!thelong) return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);` to get default-handling for all those early messages?

Comment: That's what I meant. Every WinClass has a WNDCLASSEX member that it uses with `RegisterClass`. But no matter what arguments are supplied to a WinClass's constructor, it always uses dummyProc as its handler in its WNDCLASSEX member when registering. That's what I meant.

Comment: Oh, ... usually one doesn't register a separate class for each instance.  That's what confused me.

Comment: It's for each instance of WinClass, not each Window :) Anyway, your suggestion worked! Reverting to the DefWindowProc if the user long was 0 successfully got context the right value, and stopped the myHandler from dying when using a map :) HOWEVER...

Now the entire program crashes at the map iteration FOR loop. More testing shows it crashes as soon as the iterator is incremented. Creating the iterator and setting it to messageMap.begin() works, but as soon as I try to do ++it or it++, everything crashes. It does this even when I've confirmed it's not the end AND only increment once. Huh?

Comment: Remember this is all happening inside CreateWindow, which you said is in your constructor.  The end of your Window constructor hasn't been reached yet. Does that help at all?

Comment: What data type is `myClass` inside `Window`?  Is `&myClass` making a double-pointer?  Later you treat it as a single-pointer.  Guessing that is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ben Voigt says, you're not initialising your `GWLP_USERDATA` correctly, and you're also not handling the case when it hasn't yet been initialized.

Note that even your revised code is not correct. On `WM_CREATE` the `lParam` value is **not** your user data pointer. It's a pointer to a `CREATESTRUCT`, one of the members of which is your user data value.

Try the following to replace your `dummyProc` function:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK dummyProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>( reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)->lpCreateParams ));

    WinClass* context=(WinClass*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    if (!context) return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    return context->myHandler(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
```

Comment: If I try that, I get the compiler error (on the SetWindowLongPtr line) "invalid conversion from void* to LONG"... It works if I just do a simple cast to (LONG), but is that safe?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the cast.

Comment: Whoops, just edited my comment as you posted yours >_< . Is it safe to assume that cast will always work and not fail for any reason? I don't know much about the LPCREATESTRUCT.

Comment: You should use `LONG_PTR` rather than `LONG` for 64-bit compatibility.

Comment: Good spot on that issue.  I don't understand why Daniel felt that looking at the linked scratch program (which does this correctly) was optional.  And I'm still predicting trouble resulting from using `GWLP_USERDATA` to store `WinClass*` instead of `Window*`; surely the window instance will be needed at some point for correct handling.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Well, you did get his code working.  And I missed the `CREATESTRUCT` part.  It's just frustrating that he never quite listened to me.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the window creation or where the pointer gets stored into `GWL_USERDATA`.  However, irregardless of how you do that, I promise you that **there's no way to set up `GWL_USERDATA` before the first message arrives**, because **the arrival of the first message is the first time you actually know what `HWND` your new window was assigned**.

Your window procedure isn't protecting against `context` not being set yet, and then tries to call a member function on an invalid pointer, which fails in undefined ways.

Add to that the fact that `GWL_USERDATA` isn't big enough to store a pointer; you should use using `SetWindowLongPtr` and `GetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_USERDATA`.

Normally the raw window procedure has a hand in setting `GWLP_USERDATA` in the first place.  Have a look at [Raymond Chen's C++ scratch program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx).

Notice that `WM_NCCREATE` is handled inside the raw window procedure, because there's no stored pointer to dispatch to yet (it's gotten from the `WM_NCCREATE` message arguments, not from the window).  And that isn't even the first message (you'll get `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` first in many cases), although it is the first message where the pointer can be obtained without tricks like thread-local storage.

Comment: The window creation simply passes a pointer to the relevant WinClass instance into GWL_USERDATA. I'm not setting it up BEFORE the message arrives; the dummyProc only fires when the messages arrive.

I know that's not the issue, because as I said, the function does get called and the first part outputs just fine. Everything in myHandler works up until I try to use the map. If the context weren't set properly, the function would never get called.

Comment: @DanielBurnett: You are basing all your analysis on "If the context weren't set properly, the function would never get called." which is unfortunately totally wrong.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry if that sounded a bit arrogant. As it turns out, you're right; context is just being set to NULL. I don't understand then how the myHandler is even being called with a NULL pointer there...

Anyway, on further testing, I've found that oddly enough, the WM_CREATE message is not being sent. I'll update the original post with the window creation code, and maybe that will help?

Comment: @DanielBurnett: This is how.  Your line `context->myHandler(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);` after compilation is pretty much the same as `__WinClass_myHandler(context, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);`.  The compiler knows at compile-time exactly what function to call because it isn't virtual, and happily calls the function with a bad `context` pointer.  For virtual functions, it behaves more like `auto fn = context->__vtbl[__vslot_myHandler]; (*fn)(context, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);` and that will fail if `context` is invalid because it can't find the v-table.

Comment: I think the issue here is the use of CALLBACK in your non static method myHandler. Please remove it. CALLBACK is essentially a __stdcall.

Comment: @Maf: That really isn't making any difference one way or the other.